# How to use dictionary to evaluate input of two variables in python

Tags: python

Inititally what I would like to do is **convert** two variables into a value and key and then use them **to evaluate** against a constant dictionary.

Desired output:

Enter your task: framing

Enter (LF) Linear Feet: 1200

Framing job is estimated at $7,800

```
class Lookup(dict):
    """
    a dictionary class which can lookup value by key, or keys by value
    """
    def __init__(self, items=[]):
        """items can be a list of pair_lists or a dictionary"""
        dict.__init__(self, items)

    def get_key(self, value):
        """find the key(s) as a list given a value"""
        return [item[0] for item in self.items() if item[1] == value]

    def get_value(self, key):
        """find the value given a key"""
        return self[key]

   def find_key(dic, val):
        """return the key of dictionary dic given the value"""
        return [k for k, v in job_dic.iteritems() if v == val][0]

   def find_value(dic, key):
        """return the value of dictionary dic given the key"""
        return dic[key]

class JobLookup(dict):
    """
    Where job type and linear feet are input by the user  
    """
    def __init__(self, jobvalue="None", specs="0"):
        self.jobvalue = str(input("Enter your task: ") # e.g. framing
        self.specs = int(input("Enter (LF): ")) # e.g. 1200 (LF = linear feet)

    def find_key(dic, val):
        """return the key of dictionary dic given the value"""
        return [k for k, v in job_dic.iteritems() if v == val][0]

    def find_value(dic, key):
        """return the value of dictionary dic given the key"""
        return dic[key]

    def getjobkey(self, jobvalue, specs):
        """ user inputs job to bid """
        while True: 
            if jobvalue == any (job_dict.find_value(job_dict)):
                return self[key]* specs # 7,800  e.g. 1200 * 6.50

if __name__ == "__main__":

# dictionary of interior wall jobs 
job_dic = {
'layout': .40, 
'framing': 6.50, 
'blocking': 500.00,
'insulation': .95,
'firetape': .95,  
'hanging': 8.50,
'finishing': 5.75,
'punchout': 6.50
}
```

right now I'm getting

```
>>>NameError : name 'JobLookup' is not defined.
```

I'm not even sure if this code is the right way of comparing two values and subsequently evaluating (in this case multiplying) their corresponding keys.  Is there an easier way to achieve this task?

If the input jobvalue == "value" use the key found in value.job_dict [] and multiply it by the spec input given by user.  Providing that value exists in job_dict.

Comment: in which line are you getting that error? can you post the full traceback?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your code is supposed to do.  Can you explain what you need to be able to do, so we can try to help you pick a better approach?  Examples of your input and expected output would go a long way at this point.

Comment: I will update the comment to add more details on what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: `str(input("Enter your task: ")` is missing a bracket

Answer (score 1):

If you need a dictionary that goes both ways, use two dictionaries.